# How to check if a user is logged in (how to properly use user.is_authenticated)?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am looking over [this website](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) but just can't seem to figure out how to do this as it's not working. I need to check if the current site user is logged in (authenticated), and am trying:

```
request.user.is_authenticated
```

despite being sure that the user is logged in, it returns just:

```
>
```

I'm able to do other requests (from the first section in the url above), such as:

```
request.user.is_active
```

which returns a successful response.

Comment: is_authenticated (both inside and outside templates) always returns True - regardless of whether the user is actually logged in or not. To truely identify if a user is logged in, the only solution seems to be to compare their last_seen date/time with the timeout

Answer (score 648, accepted):

## Update for Django 2.0 and later

`is_authenticated` is an **attribute**

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # do something if the user is authenticated
```

---

##### For Django 1.9 and older

`is_authenticated()` was a function. Called like:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # do something if the user is authenticated
```

As Peter Rowell pointed out, what may be tripping you up is that in the default Django template language, you don't tack on parenthesis to call functions. So you may have seen something like this in template code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

However, in Python code, it is indeed a method in the `User` class.

*NB: The method was removed in Django 2.0.*

Comment: oh ok.. thanks for the info, that makes sense then why it wasn't working, unless I missed something, it is really not clear about this in the django documentation

Comment: @Rick: I beg to differ with you. is_authenticated() is the second item listed in the *methods* section of class models.User. What may be confusing is that the *template language* does *not* use the trailing ()'s, so you might see something like {% if user.is_authenticated %}. You'll get an error if you put the ()'s in. (See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated and http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#variables)

Comment: @Peter, well they don't use () in the examples, I realize that I am sure they explained somewhere that its a method and how to do it properly, its just nice when an API uses real life syntax in it so that it can be quickly taken in by someone new to a project like Django, just a pet peeve I guess as I tend to skim through things but I realize I should have looked closer, thanks for the help

Comment: @Rick: I completely agree with you about real life syntax. I have heard the (what I consider) lame reasons they have for not using a "real" programming language for the template system, but that's what they did. You can choose to use Jinja2 (http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) and it will give you full Python capabilities, but since the overwhelming majority of 3rd party apps use the Django system it is often hard to intermix them. Look at ExprTag (http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/) for a way to get expressions inside of Django templates. It works.

Comment: @Rick the documentation says different things for different version. Looks like for 1.10 it's no longer a method

Comment: @yairchu that is good to know, if perhaps not what tripped up @Rick!

Comment: didn't know user object is available in template, I previously thought it was request.user

Comment: @minhajul If you have the `auth` template context processor enabled (it is by default) and you use `RequestContext` to render the template, you get `request` and `user` in the template context. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#users

Comment: andis_authenticated (both inside and outside templates) always returns True - regardless of whether the user is actually logged in or not.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 what?

Comment: @BrianNeal using ``user.is_authenticated`` will ALWAYS return True if the user has logged in at all. I don't know whether ``request.user`` is always that same as ``user`` in all cases. I know that when you call logoff the session data that ``request`` is derived from is cleared and request.user is set to Anonymous and at that point request.user.is_authenticated will be False.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 What you are describing contradicts my experience with using `user` in a template and the auth context processor. If you are still having trouble you might want to open a separate question describing your problem.

Comment: @BrianNeal - I am not having a problem - I never try to confirm the logged in (or not) in my views - I use loginrequired (decorator or Mixin) and have different views for logged in or not - but that is just me :-)

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 `user.is_authenticated` is very useful in templates when you want to show different things to authenticated vs non-authenticated users. Your claim that it always returns True would mean Django has a serious bug that no one else has noticed. Anyway... no use arguing about it here in the comments of an unrelated question.

Comment: It isn't a 'serious bug' - it is a documented feature: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#attributes

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I guess maybe we are talking past each other here. If you use the auth context processor and then access `{{ user }}` in your template, you are either going to get a real `User` instance, in which, yes, `.is_authenticated` will always return true, or you are going to get an `AnonymousUser` instance in which it will return false. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth  I was referring to the combination of auth context processor and using `{{ user }}` in a template context.

Comment: is there any way to optimize the way we check if a user is logged-in or not in each view separately?

Comment: what is the alternative for django 2.0+?

Comment: @py_ios_dev - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Comment: remove the () at the end, it is not a method or function it is an object. use  this: current_user.is_authenticated

Comment: for django 3+ if request.user.is_authenticated:

Answer (score 62):

**Django 1.10+**

Use an attribute, *not* a method:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated: # <-  no parentheses any more!
    # do something if the user is authenticated
```

The use of the method of the same name is deprecated in Django 2.0, and is no longer mentioned in the Django documentation.

---

Note that for Django 1.10 and 1.11, the value of the property is a `CallableBool` and not a boolean, which can cause some strange bugs. 
 For example, I had a view that returned JSON

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
    "is_authenticated": request.user.is_authenticated()
}), content_type='application/json')
```

that after updated to the property `request.user.is_authenticated` was throwing the exception `TypeError: Object of type 'CallableBool' is not JSON serializable`.  The solution was to use JsonResponse, which could handle the CallableBool object properly when serializing:

```
return JsonResponse({
    "is_authenticated": request.user.is_authenticated
})
```

Comment: but is_authenticated (both inside and outside templates) always returns True for a real user (and False for an anonymous user) - regardless of whether the user is actually logged in or not.

Comment: That's okay because this method is used on `request.user`.  Whether a user is logged in or not only matters in the context of the request, for example the browser session.

Comment: Assuming the application correctly logs out users - I have seen some that don't.

Answer (score 32):

Following block should work:

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome {{ user.username }} !!!</p>       
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: but is_authenticated (both inside and outside templates) always returns True - regardless of whether the user is actually logged in or not.

Comment: The document says: 

Read-only attribute which is always True (as opposed to AnonymousUser.is_authenticated which is always False). This is a way to tell if the user has been authenticated. This does not imply any permissions and doesn’t check if the user is active or has a valid session. Even though normally you will check this attribute on request.user to find out whether it has been populated by the AuthenticationMiddleware (representing the currently logged-in user), you should know this attribute is True for any User instance.

Comment: So if you want to display - un-authenticated users as "Welcome Guest" and authenticate users as "Welcome .USERNAME" then following block in templates can work: 


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
               <p>Welcome {{ user.username }} !!!</p>
            {% else %}
               <p>Welcome Guest!!! </p>
           {% endif %}

Answer (score 10):

In your view:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>{{ user }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

In you controller functions add decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def privateFunction(request):
```

Comment: but is_authenticated (both inside and outside templates) always returns True - regardless of whether the user is actually logged in or not.

Comment: better to user `request.user.is_authenticated` if you know that your application will always log the user out

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check for authenticated users in your template then:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Authenticated user</p>
{% else %}
    <!-- Do something which you want to do with unauthenticated user -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -2):

to check if user is logged-in (authenticated user) in views.py file, use "is_authenticated" method, as the following example:

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print('yes the user is logged-in')
    else:
        print('no the user is not logged-in')
```

to check if user is logged-in (authenticated user) in your html templates file you can use it also as the following example :

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome,{{request.user.first_name}}           

 {% endif %}
```

this is just example , and change it based on your requirements.

i hope this helpful for you .

Answer (score -6):

For **Django 2.0+** versions use:

```
    if request.auth:
       # Only for authenticated users.
```

For more info visit https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#auth

request.user.is_authenticated() has been removed in Django 2.0+ versions.

Comment: `request.user.is_authenticated` is still valid. You are referencing django-rest-framework documentation not [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)