# How to cache view for all users in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to use a Memcached instance of AWS ElastiCache with a Django project.  It seems to be caching a view for a user, but if you come in on a different PC, it isn't cached until called from that PC (or same PC with different browser).

I'm not sure what I've got wrong.

Within `settings.py` I have

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': os.environ.get('CACHE_LOCATION','127.0.0.1:11211'),
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'core.middleware.DenyIndexMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.XForwardedForMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.PrimaryHostRedirectMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
    'masquerade.middleware.MasqueradeMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

I've then  cached the views using `cache_page`

```
path('<str:service_type>/<str:location>/', cache_page(60*60)(views.canonical_search), name="canonical-search"),
```

How do I cache the site so that the page is cached irrespective of the user?

**EDIT**
I've noticed that it never caches when using the user is logged in.

Comment: Hello! Is the URL the same for all users? I suspect it is, but if it's not, there lies the problem, since the cache system caches on a per-URL basis instead of on a per-view basis.

Comment: url is the same for all users

Comment: By user, do you mean logged-in/anonymous? Is there any cache policy in your web server (nginx/apache)?

Comment: @SebCorbin I'm using ElasticBeanstalk and I've not set any cache explicitly.  I don't know if ElasticBeanstalk has

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watch out for the `Vary` header, that `cache_page()` takes into account.

Usually, some middlewares may add a `Vary` header, for example :

- `CsrfViewMiddleware` adds `Cookie`,
- `GZipMiddleware`adds `Accept-Encoding`
- `LanguageCookieMiddleware` may add `Accept-Language`

meaning that as soon as you have a different Cookie (session), encoding, or language, you have a different version of cache for your page.

As for you case, the `CsrfViewMiddleware` may be the problem, you can add the decorator [`@csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) to your view so that the `Vary: Cookie` header is not set in the response.

More info at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers

Comment: Then I suggest you inspect the requests and responses both browsers send and receive, to compare `Vary` header of the response and the headers sent by the browsers.

Comment: The `Vary` header in both says `vary: Accept-Language,Cookie,X-Forwarded-Proto,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent`  I don't understand what this is telling me

Comment: So yeah, you have a lot a possible variations, I suggest you search for `Vary` or `Cookie` in the middlewares you are using and try to debug which one is adding it. Also `User-Agent` is surely  a probable cause for cache miss.

Comment: What do I do once I've found which one is varying it?

Comment: How do I tell it not to vary on headers?

Comment: Well you have to read the documentation about this middleware and see if there is a flag to cancel/understand with it's setting the `Vary ` value. As a last resort, you can write your own middleware, place it after in the list, and remove the value from `Vary` but it would advise against it.

Answer (score 2):

Though `Django` documentation, you can read this:
[Django’s cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/)

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

If you need to store a page in the local

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'c:/foo/bar',
    }
}
```

But, my recommendation is store the results (database result, assets, etc), as @PVSK show in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241407/how-use-django-cache-in-view-without-cache-all-page):

```
from django.core.cache import cache    
def sample(request):
        cached_data = cache.get_many(['query1', 'query2'])
        if cached_data:
            return render(request, 'sample.html', {'query1': cached_data['query1'], 'query2': cached_data['query2']})
        else:
            queryset1 = Model.objects.all()
            queryset2 = Model2.objects.all()
            cache.set_many({'query1': queryset1 , 'query2': queryset2 }, None)
            return render(request, 'sample.html', {'query1': queryset1 , 'query2': queryset2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, at first I wondered if you're running into some cache default limitations. You are not using `OPTIONS` in your `CACHE` backend definition, so the cache is limited to 300 entries per default.

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': os.environ.get('CACHE_LOCATION','127.0.0.1:11211'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 1000
        }

    }
}
```

The next possible problem, that we also had, is that the cache_key generation takes the full QUERY_STRING into account, so  (the `?param=bla`). But you already stated that the url is the same for all users.

Next up, as SebCorbin correctly identified, are the potential `Vary` issues.

`UpdateCacheMiddleware` will never cache a cookie-setting response to a cookie-less request.

```py
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        #...

        # Don't cache responses that set a user-specific (and maybe security
        # sensitive) cookie in response to a cookie-less request.
        if not request.COOKIES and response.cookies and has_vary_header(response, 'Cookie'):
            return response

        # ...
```

The order of execution of middlewares is **top-to-bottom** for `process_request` and **bottom-to-top** for `process_response`.

I suspect that one of lower middlewares (or the view) is setting a cookie, so you might be able to work around this issue by moving the `'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware'` below the offending middleware, but you risk loosing features if you don't move feature-middlewares like `LocaleMiddleware` as well.

If your view code is setting cookies you'll need to switch to the low-level cache API to cache costly operations (or move the cookie logic into a middleware that lives above the `UpdateCacheMiddleware` middleware).