# Check if there is someone logged in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a new django project I am working on. I am integrating Djangos user login and logout service that comes with the framework. I have a view and within the view, I want to check and see if there is a `user` object in the `request.user`. if there is not, I want to redirect to login page. If there is a `user` in the `request.user`, I want to display the users home page. how can I do this. Here is my code:

```
def home(request):
    if not request.user:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        User = request.user
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = User)
        parameters = {
            'user':User,
            'profile':profile,
        }
        return render(request, 'user/home.html', parameters)
```

It works if there is a user logged in but doesnt work if there is no user logged in...

Comment: There are many examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644910/2282638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def home(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        User = request.user
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = User)
        parameters = {
            'user':User,
            'profile':profile,
        }
        return render(request, 'user/home.html', parameters)
```

you need to check whether the user is authenticated or not, if you check `request.user` django will return anonymous user as default

Comment: Note that [`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) was made into an attribute rather than a method in Django 1.10.

Comment: You don't need `else` since it will return if user isn't logged in anyway

Answer (score 2):

Django [provides a decorator for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    # at this point you know you _always_ have an authenticated user
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    context = {
        'user':user,
        'profile':profile,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1):

you have two options,

option 1:

to check if user is logged-in (authenticated user) inside your views, use "is_authenticated", as the following example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def home(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        print('no, the user is not logged-in')
        return redirect('login')
      
    return render(request, 'user/home.html', parameters)
```

---

option 2:

by using'login_required' decorator :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required(login_url='/login')  #url you want to redirected to 
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'user/home.html', parameters)
```

this is just example , and change it based on your requirements.

i hope this helpful for you .