# Django: Redirect to different page if logged in in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have this url:

```
url(r'^signup/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='users/signup.html')),
```

and I want the user to be redirected to a different url, if they try access this page and are already logged in.

Is there anyway I can do this in the urls.py or will I have to write a view for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do it in urls.py and so would do this in the view.

You can check using this:

`if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Do something`

You can also do this in the template:

`{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

This question may be helpful:
[How to check if a user is logged in (how to properly use user.is_authenticated)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644902/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-how-to-properly-use-user-is-authenticated)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

Something like this

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def signup(request): # this is your signup view
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
```

And looks like there's also a [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut (which ultimately also does an `HttpResponseRedirect`).