# How to save custom User model in Django during user's navigation

Tags: python, django, session

Hy guys, I have a custom User model in Django 2.0 containing various user data.

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    _isLogged = False
    # ... other custom data
```

Once the user is logged (`_isLogged = True`)~ in the login page, how can I save this object  so I can verify in another page, say home, that the same user has already logged in?

N.B. I tried to store all the object in a session variable but it is not serializable.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if user is logged by calling the `is_authenticated` function:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # something
```

This is already well described in the similar post: [How to check if a user is logged in (how to properly use user.is_authenticated)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644902/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-how-to-properly-use-user-is-authenticated)

You *don't need* any special fields (like `_isLogged`) if 1) you're using default Django User, 2) you extend default User model or 3) you properly configured your own model.

For details consult the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

#### Edit: "How I should "properly" configure my own model?"

This is very well describied in the following [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). In short:

1. You declare your User model subclassing the `AbstractUser` class:

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

   class User(AbstractUser):
       pass
   ```
2. You override the default User model by setting the following value in Django settings:

   ```
   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
   ```

Comment: I'd go for the option 3) but can you explain how I should "properly" configure my own model???

Comment: Thank you, but the Django-way to do this is rather obscure... For example in the documentation I cannot find how to define my `is_authenticated()` method. I still prefer to do my custom model and check data using session, separated from Django user model.

Comment: What do you mean by define? is_authenticated is a default method, you can use it out-of-the-box or override it using Python.

Comment: How does a user become "authenticated"? I have a special test to do before checking username and password.