# working with {% if %} {% else %} in Django

Tags: python, html, django

how can I hide user name from login page with If-Statement.
Im using this code to show the user name in the main page after login in, and it's working

```
{%if request.user.first_name%}{{request.user.first_name}}{%else%}{{user}}{%endif%}
```

but the problem is that it's shown in the login page too as "AnonymousUser". how can I hide this

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}{% endif %}
```

Related:
[How to check if a user is logged in (how to properly use user.is_authenticated)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644902/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-how-to-properly-use-user-is-authenticated)

Answer (score 3):

**Firstly you should check if user is authenticated** and if authenticated show the first_name or username else just give link to login and signup.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   {%if request.user.first_name%}
      {{request.user.first_name}}
   {%else%}
      {{request.user.username}}
   {%endif%}
{% else %}
  <a href="" >login</a>
  <a href="" >Signup</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`.is_authenticated`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) here:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} ... {% endif %}
```

For a user that is not authenticated (like an `AnonymousUser`) the check will fail.