# how to check if a user is logged in when using third party login system?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a web app which is based on django (version 2.0+), the user can only login with third party authentication.

My question is like, can I still use the technique like:

```
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

(source: [How to check if a user is logged in (how to properly use user.is_authenticated)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644902/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-how-to-properly-use-user-is-authenticated))

to see if user is logged in?

Some background: After third party login, user profile is available. At the moment the structure of the database is still at design phase.

Comment: Yes, you should implement an authentication backend that uses your 3rd party API to authenticate users instead of the default username/password authentication Django provides. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#other-authentication-sources) to find out more.

Comment: the document is exactly what I need, Thanks so much. :)