# if user.is_authenticated not getting logged in user django

Tags: python, django

Entirely new to python and django framework.

Trying to build a login/registration system.'

After registering, redirects to home but user is not authenticated (returns false always)

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        fullname = form.cleaned_data.get('fullname')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, fullname=fullname, password=password)
        messages.success(request, f'Welcome to blaza {fullname}')
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()

return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Home {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
Welcome, {{user.username}}!
<a href="">Logout</a>
{% else %}
<P>You are not logged in</P>
<p><a href="">Login here</a></p>
{% endif %}  
{% endblock %}
```

It returns false always. "You are not logged".

I have tried *{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}* still not working.

Answer (score 0):

‍‍`i‍‍s‍_authenticated` is a method not a property. I think you forgot the parenthesis.
Try this:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated() %}
```

Comment: Ttemplate syntax error. Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'request.user.is_authenticated()'

Comment: My bad. I am using django 1.8 where is_authenticated is method. It was changed after 1.10+ versions of django. Refer to this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644902/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-how-to-properly-use-user-is-authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved the user after signing up ?

> myuser.save()

I have attached the code which worked for me.

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.POST['username']
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
    pass2 = request.POST['pass2']
    myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email)
    myuser.set_password(pass1)
    myuser.us_name = name
    myuser.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your account has been sucessfully created. ")
    return redirect('signin')
return render(request, "authentication/signup.html")
```